# How to enable bulk amount of option values in html selection drop down box?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know a way to enable all the times in this selection box without having to go through them with "document.getElementById". There are about 30 of these, for all the times.

In the live code, the option values (times) can be disabled depending on a date selection, so at the start of the function (onchange event) it enables them all for use again (and disables per date selected).

```
<select name="time" id="time">
<option value="N/A">Select</option>
<option value="12:00pm" id="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
<option value="12:15pm" id="12:15pm">12:15pm</option>
<option value="12:30pm" id="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
<option value="12:45pm" id="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
<option value="13:00pm" id="13:00pm">13:00pm</option>
<option value="13:15pm" id="13:15pm">13:15pm</option>
<option value="13:30pm" id="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
<option value="13:45pm" id="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
<option value="14:00pm" id="14:00pm">14:00pm</option>
</select>

<script>
var select = document.getElementById('date');
select.onchange = SetClosed;
window.onload = SetClosed;

function SetClosed(){
document.getElementById("12:00pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("12:15pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("12:30pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("12:45pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("13:00pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("13:15pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("13:30pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("13:45pm").disabled = false;
document.getElementById("14:00pm").disabled = false;
}
</script>
```

i have tried this to replace the large amounts of "getElementById", but no joy:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[name="time"]').forEach(element => {element.removeAttribute("disabled");});
```

The code works using ID's of course, but was hoping there could be a way to reduce the code down a bit.

Comment: Give a same class to every elements and then removing disabled attr? Im not sure abt it ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parent child selectors in `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('select#time option').forEach(element => {element.removeAttribute("disabled");});
```

Comment: Cheers Melvin, this works a charm! Although this solution will not work in IE11, so i guess until next year (15th June 2022, IE11 removed from windows) i will just have to keep the bulky ID code for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You are tryng to achieve somthing like this?

```js
function reenable(){
  document.querySelectorAll('select[name=time] option').forEach(ele => {
    ele.disabled=false;
  });
}
```

```html
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<select name="time">
  <option value="N/A">Select</option>
  <option value="12:00pm">12:00pm</option>
  <option value="12:15pm" disabled>12:15pm</option>
  <option value="12:30pm">12:30pm</option>
  <option value="12:45pm">12:45pm</option>
  <option value="13:00pm" disabled>13:00pm</option>
  <option value="13:15pm" disabled>13:15pm</option>
  <option value="13:30pm">13:30pm</option>
  <option value="13:45pm">13:45pm</option>
  <option value="14:00pm" disabled>14:00pm</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<button onclick='reenable()'>Enable All</button>
```